# String to Date Conversion in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica-powercenter

I wanted to convert my string 'Jan 22,2021' to date 01/22/2021.
I used TO_DATE() function for it but it does not work. it shows invalid string.
What changes I must do to get desired result

Comment: For future questions, show what you tried and what error you received.

Comment: Can you debug code that you cannot see? No? Of course not. So don't expect it of others.  _SHOW_ us (copy'n'paste) the statement that "does not work", as well as the results that it gave.  Also realize that to_date returns a DATE data type, which is an internal binary structure.  In order to _display_ the resulting DATE, you will need to pass the result to TO_CHAR.  If you don't do that explicitly, oracle will do it implicitly, but may very well not use the display format you want.  See https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try with a style parameter?

```
select to_date( 'Jan 22,2021', 'Mon DD,YYYY')
from dual;
```